# jquery and coffeescript .keyup trigger

Tags: jquery, coffeescript

Trying to change value with jQuery (preferably Coffeescript) `.keyup` of `#submitter_email` to have `#submitter_first_name + "." + #submitter_last_name`.

Just for clarity:
When `#submitter_first_name` value = "Bob" and
When `#submitter_last_name` value = "Evans" then
`#submitter_email` value = "Bob.Evans"

Sorry folks - the question here is how to do this?

Here is the code I came up with that makes sense to me logically, but it's obviously not correct:

```
jQuery ->
a = $("#submitter_first_name").val
b = $("#submitter_last_name").val
c = $("#submitter_email").val
a.keyup, b.keyup ->
c.val a + "." + b
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to bind the events to the value of those inputs. Try this:

```
jQuery ->
    a = $("#submitter_first_name")
    b = $("#submitter_last_name")
    c = $("#submitter_email")

    a.add(b).keyup -> (
        c.val a.val() + "." + b.val()
    )
```

This fiddle works with the code generated by the above coffeescript. http://jsfiddle.net/yuHbp/.

Comment: Thanks for the help this doesn't seem to be working though. I had a syntax error in my orignal code so I removed the `,` and made it `a.keyup b.keyup ->` with your code and still no luck.

Comment: That works! This is great. I didn't realize I'd have to do the `a.add(b)` part. I would have never figured this out.  Thanks so much.

Comment: You can use CoffeeScript at jsfiddle.net, look under *Languages* in the sidebar: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/BSyk6/

Comment: @muistooshort - Thanks, didn't know that, I'll keep it in mind